# ¿Existe y cuál es el prefijo para hacia delante/futuras?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Existe el prefijo retro- que indica "hacia atrás" o "del pasado" y mi pregunta es sí existe un prefijo para indicar "hacia delante" o "del futuro". Y en caso de existir ¿cuál es el prefijo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**pro-**:

> Del lat. *pro-.*
>   1. pref. Significa 'por' o 'en vez de'. *Pronombre, procónsul.*
>   2. pref. Significa 'ante', 'delante de', **'hacia delante'**. *Prólogo, progenitura, proseguir.*
>   3. pref. Significa 'en favor de', 'partidario de'. *Proamnistía, progubernamental. Asociaciones pro derechos humanos.*

[[RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UDfB2vM)]

Ejemplo:

- [Prospectivo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UQfWOEp): 1. adj. Que se refiere al futuro.

De "pro" (hacia delante) y "spicere" (mirar), algo es prospectivo si "mira hacia delante o al futuro". Compárese con "introspectivo" (mirar hacia dentro) y "retrospectivo" (mirar hacia atrás).